# How do I properly rotate a vector to match another? (OPENGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, vector, glm-math

I have been struggling with the following problem for some time: I have a program that allows users to draw Bezier curves of various lengths (4 points for the first, 3 for all others, simply connecting the curves one after another). I need to place small rectangular train tracks along the curve to let the user ride around the track they made. I've defined the vertices already, and made a method to place them properly on the line, but the rotation has proven to be tricky. For smooth curves, my current implementation works fine, but sharp corners cause the tracks to no longer align, and all tracks past that corner have the exact same rotation, breaking it completely. All relevant code is below:

Code for filling the curve std::vector with points:

```
p0 = glm::vec2(pointVertexData.at(0), pointVertexData.at(1));
p1 = glm::vec2(pointVertexData.at(3), pointVertexData.at(4));
p2 = glm::vec2(pointVertexData.at(6), pointVertexData.at(7));
p3 = glm::vec2(pointVertexData.at(9), pointVertexData.at(10));
curveVertexData = Subdivide(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.05f, curveVertexData);
for (int i = 0; i < timesToLoop; i++)
{
    p0 = p3;
    p1 = glm::vec2(pointVertexData.at(n), pointVertexData.at(n+1));
    p2 = glm::vec2(pointVertexData.at(n+3), pointVertexData.at(n+4));
    p3 = glm::vec2(pointVertexData.at(n+6), pointVertexData.at(n+7));
    std::vector<GLfloat> tempVec = Subdivide(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.05f, tempVec);
    curveVertexData.insert(curveVertexData.end(), tempVec.begin()+3, tempVec.end());
}
```

Code for the subdivision:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> Subdivide(GLfloat u0, GLfloat u1, GLfloat maxLineLength, std::vector<GLfloat> recurVertices)
{
    GLfloat umid = (u0 + u1) / 2.0;
    glm::vec2 x0 = Interpolate(p0, p1, p2, p3, u0, pFinal);
    glm::vec2 x1 = Interpolate(p0, p1, p2, p3, u1, pFinal);
    GLfloat length = sqrt(pow((x1.x - x0.x), 2) + pow((x1.y - x0.y), 2));
    if (length > maxLineLength)
    {
        std::vector<GLfloat> firstVertices = Subdivide(u0, umid, maxLineLength, firstVertices);
        std::vector<GLfloat> secondVertices = Subdivide(umid, u1, maxLineLength, secondVertices);
        secondVertices.insert(secondVertices.begin(), firstVertices.begin(), firstVertices.end()-3);
        recurVertices = secondVertices;
        return recurVertices;
    }
    else
    {
        recurVertices.push_back(x0.x);
        recurVertices.push_back(x0.y);
        recurVertices.push_back(0.1f);
        recurVertices.push_back(x1.x);
        recurVertices.push_back(x1.y);
        recurVertices.push_back(0.1f);
        numberOfVertices += 6;
        return recurVertices;
    }
}
```

Code for setting up the std::vector with the vertices of the tracks:

```
    std::vector<GLfloat> tempVertices;
    numberOfTrackVertices = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < curveVertexData.size() - 2; i+=3)
    {
        std::cout << "Now calculating point # " << i << " : ";
        if(i != 0 && i < curveVertexData.size() - 5)
            shiftVertices(trainVertices, curveVertexData[i], curveVertexData[i + 1], curveVertexData[i + 2], curveVertexData[i + 3], curveVertexData[i + 4], curveVertexData[i + 5], curveVertexData[i - 3], curveVertexData[i - 2], curveVertexData[i - 1], &tempVertices);
        else if (i == 0)
            shiftVertices(trainVertices, curveVertexData[i], curveVertexData[i + 1], curveVertexData[i + 2], curveVertexData[i + 3], curveVertexData[i + 4], curveVertexData[i + 5], curveVertexData[i], curveVertexData[i + 1], curveVertexData[i + 2], &tempVertices);
        else
            shiftVertices(trainVertices, curveVertexData[i], curveVertexData[i + 1], curveVertexData[i + 2], curveVertexData[i], curveVertexData[i + 1], curveVertexData[i + 2], curveVertexData[i - 3], curveVertexData[i - 2], curveVertexData[i - 1], &tempVertices);
    }
```

And, finally, the code that I think is the most likely culprit, the code used to shift the rotation of the tracks. My current algorithm is as follows:
(Note that the reason "currentOrientation" is set equal to the first two elements of the vertices subtracted by each other is because they represent the lower back corners of the rectangle, which, when subtracted by each other, gives a vector representing which way the box is oriented)

```
    void shiftVertices(GLfloat inVertices[], GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat rx, GLfloat ry, GLfloat rz, GLfloat qx, GLfloat qy, GLfloat qz, std::vector<GLfloat> *container)
{
    glm::vec3 tempVectors[36];
    glm::vec3 moveVector = glm::vec3(x, y, z);
    glm::vec3 rotateVector = glm::normalize(glm::vec3(rx - qx, ry - qy, rz - qz));
    rotateVector = glm::normalize(glm::cross(rotateVector, UP));
    bool unFilled = true;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(unFilled)
    {
        tempVectors[n].x = inVertices[i];
        i++;
        tempVectors[n].y = inVertices[i];
        i++;
        tempVectors[n].z = inVertices[i];
        i++;
        n++;
        if (n >= 36)
            unFilled = false;
    }
    glm::vec3 currentOrientation = glm::normalize(tempVectors[0] - tempVectors[1]);
    GLfloat angleToRotate = glm::acos(glm::dot(currentOrientation, rotateVector));
    angleToRotate = (180.0f * angleToRotate) / PI;
    std::cout << angleToRotate << "\n";
    glm::mat4 rotationMatrix;
    rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(rotationMatrix, angleToRotate, UP);
    for (int u = 0; u < 36; u++)
    {
        tempVectors[u] = glm::vec3(rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(tempVectors[u], 1.0));
        tempVectors[u] = tempVectors[u] + moveVector;
    }
    i = 0;
    n = 0;
    unFilled = true;
    while (unFilled)
    {
        container->push_back(tempVectors[n].x);
        container->push_back(tempVectors[n].y);
        container->push_back(tempVectors[n].z);
        numberOfTrackVertices++;
        n++;
        if (n >= 36)
            unFilled = false;
    }
}
```

This implementation gives the following results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7gbr.jpg (All but last image. Sorry, it won't let me embed images)

I have looked up many resources for this, with little success. One implementation was Jur van den Berg's answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d
Note that I refer to this as the "skew-symmetric method" in the images.
My implementation of the algorithm is as follows, and, as previously stated, does not function properly:
(Note that this code replaces the middle section of code in the last sample, with the loops before and after staying the same)

```
        glm::vec3 crossVector = glm::cross(currentOrientation, rotateVector);
        GLfloat sineAngle = crossVector.length();
        GLfloat cosAngle = glm::dot(currentOrientation, rotateVector);
        glm::mat3 experimentalRMatrix;
        glm::mat3 skewSymmetric = { 0, (-1.0f * crossVector.z), crossVector.y,
            crossVector.z, 0, (-1.0f *crossVector.x),
            (-1.0f * crossVector.y), crossVector.x, 0 };
        glm::mat3 skewSecond = skewSymmetric * skewSymmetric;
        skewSecond = skewSecond * ((1.0f - cosAngle) / (sineAngle * sineAngle));
        experimentalRMatrix = glm::mat3() + skewSymmetric + skewSecond;
        testVector = experimentalRMatrix * currentOrientation;
        rotationMatrix = glm::mat4(experimentalRMatrix);
```

With all this on the table, I am hoping for an analysis into why my attempts to solve the issue have failed, and/or a solution that will correctly rotate the vertices.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: What you need is a good "frame" along your curve. A classic solution is the frenet frame. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Comment: What you need is a good "frame" along your curve. A classic solution is the frenet frame. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas
But it might not be useful in practice. If you are interactive the best approach is just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process
and picking a screen space up vector. 
In practice, take your tangent on the curve. Transform it to view space (tv). Then pick screen space up as nv=(0,1,0). Compute bv=tv x nv. (x is cross product). Then nv2 = bv x tv. And your frame is (tv,bv,nv2).

Comment: tangent space is the way to go here, but where the two curves meet you should be expecting it to be disjoint (input curve 2). you can help mitigate that potentially by (when the user connects two curves) injecting a control point from the one you are merging with (to both!)? also you are asking how to "properly rotate vectors", the defacto answer would be to use quaternions. plus, if you make the switch to quaternions, you get [slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) for free. and `glm` makes them [easy](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/) :)

Comment: @sjm324 Thank you very much! I switched to using quaternions, and it works beautifully! Even on sharp corners, it will always correct itself. I appreciate the solutions given by you and starmole, and will be making sure to use quaternions from now on.

Comment: yay!  i wasn't sure that was your problem but I'm glad it worked, quaternions are pure magic. provided an "answer" so it can be closed as far as SO is concerned

Answer (score 0):

see comments...tangent spaces and quaternions seem to have done the trick